# How to fix different return types + simplify expression

Tags: java, list, collections, incompatibletypeerror, empty-list

I want to get following method runnable:

```
  private List<Object[]> getDatabaseRecords(Product p, Set<LocalDate> months) {
    return (List<Object[]>)MappingUtils.getSomethingByProduct(p)
        .map(x -> dataAccess.findAll(new NativeDataQuery<>(createSqlForSomeStuff(new TreeSet<LocalDate>(months), x, p))))
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
  }
```

But getting below error:

```
Error:(253, 19) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Object[]>
```

Alternative solution that runs is:

```
 private List<Object[]> getDatabaseRecords(Product p, Set<LocalDate> months) {
   Optional<Class<? extends Base>> foo = MappingUtils.getSomethingByProduct(p);
    return foo.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() :
        dataAccess.findAll(...);
  }
```

Comment: findAll definition is: <T> List<T> findAll(DataQuery<T> query);

Comment: line 253 is: .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);